# numpy.expand_dims equivalent in C#

Tags: python, c#, numpy

I'm trying to do the equivalent code in C# but can't find any way to do it

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([2,4])
b = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)
b
array([[2,4]])
b.shape
(1,2)
```

Comment: Explain in words (or interpretive dance), what `numpy.expand_dims` actually does (leave the python for reference), then this can be framed in a self contained way as a C# question, not just a convert my code service question

Comment: `np.expand_dims` essentially does a `np.reshape`.  `numpy` arrays can be easily reshaped, including adding size 1 dimensions.  Does `C#` have multidimensional arrays?  Ones that can be reshaped?

Comment: Numpy expand dims adds a new dimension to a array in this case it will insert the new dimension in the first index

Comment: Peter, you need to provide some basic C# code, something that creates an "array" or whatever you using instead of the `numpy` array.  Don't just ask a generic C# question.  This isn't a translation service.  Give us a [mcve] - in C#

Comment: I know C# has multi dimensional arrays not sure how to reshape them tho I'm just starting in C#

Comment: `int[] a = new[] {2, 4}; int[][] b = new[][] {a};`?

Comment: thank you this is my first time on stack overflow next time i will write a question the way described in the comments

Comment: Support for multidimensional arrays in C# is quite primitive, as that is fundamentally achieved by using 1D-arrays (of 1D-arrays)^n to have (N+1) dims (similar to Python lists). On the contrary, in NumPy they are written as plain 1D-arrays with some boilerplate (strides/views) to make it easy interpreting them in a multidimensional way. Not sure what the C# numerical ecosystem offers, but I'd look into some library mimicking NumPy's behavior, as it would otherwise be very difficult to mimic its flexibility.